# Statistical Comparison of Algorithms by User Ratings

Tags: statistical-significance, nonparametric, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, dunn-test

I have an experimental setting where I compare 3 algorithms on the same dataset(n_sources), through user subjective evaluation of the produced outcomes(each algorithm does a different kind of sound manipulation). This user evaluation is done for each of the outputs (3*n_sources), on a single Likert-type item, so the data is ordinal (not interval/scale).

I have the following doubts:
- Should I consider this setting as a repeated-measures or not? If the former, I'd use a Friedman Test, otherwise, I'd use a Kruskall-Wallis H Test.
- Assuming I'd obtain statistical significance (so, the groups were distinct in some way), what test would be better to perform the correct post-hoc analysis, to see where the differences occurred: Mann-Whitney U, Wilcoxon signed-rank test, or Dunn Test? (I've seen the 1st two used in some similar papers, and the latter recommended here in StackExchange).
- Should I use Bonferroni correction in any scenario? (only on the post-hoc analysis, right?)

Comment: +1. Just to clarify: What is it meant by `dataset(n_sources)`? Also, do you have a benchmark/existing algorithms you compare against? If it is multiple comparison among all method probably you want to do a Bergmann-Hommel procedure of adjusting your p-values.

Comment: I mean a dataset with n (n_sources) elements. I test 3 parameterisations of the algorithm, 1 is mine, the other is the default (i can consider this the benchmark), and a 3rd one which is always incorrect.